# One to Many outer join using KTable in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a table contact published to topic#1 with key as contact.id. Also a subtable is published to topic#2 with key as subtable.id. Now, I need to do a join like

```
select * from contact c  outer join subtable st on c.id = st.id;
```

There is a 1..n relationship between the tables. How to perform a aggregation with/without lambda here.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Streams API does not support 1:n KTable-KTable joins yet (version `1.0` or earlier).

The only non-primary key join supported is a KStream-GlobalKTable join.

More details about join can be found in this blog post: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/

Also, there is a JIRA for 1:n joins: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3705